Not able to access 500 GB space from my external drive
I have a 1.5 TB WD Elements hard drive. There were two containers with 500 GB space and 250 GB space respectively. I wanted to delete both of them and merge them in my 750 GB APFS volume.
I was able to delete the 250 GB container which turned into free space post which I saw the below output using diskutil list
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.5 TB     disk4
   1:                 Apple_APFS Container disk5         500.0 GB   disk4s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk7         750.1 GB   disk4s2
                    (free space)                         250.1 GB   -

After I ran sudo diskutil apfs deletecontainer disk4s1 I saw the output below:
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.5 TB     disk4
   1:                 Apple_APFS Container disk7         750.1 GB   disk4s2
                    (free space)                         250.1 GB   -

I am not able to find the additional 500 GB space anywhere.
This is the current state of my external drive after using the free space with disk4s2:
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.5 TB     disk4
   1:                 Apple_APFS Container disk5         1.0 TB     disk4s1

Please help in recovering the other 500 GB space.

I am not a disk expert by any means but in order to combine two parts of a disk they must be next to each other in the partition map. It looks like one part of the disk you want to combine was before the OS container and one part was after the OS container. You may have to back up the contents of Disk4s1 and delete it so you can then create the partition scheme you want.

Understood, I also though of this method. But I was looking for something where I will not have to do delete disk4s1

The answer depends on how much free space container disk5 (disk4s1) has. In other words, if there is enough free space then the container could be cloned instead of moved. I believe cloning is a safer operation.
